# What are some ways of showing that a structure is not minimal?

Tags: intuition, model-theory

The question is really in the title.

My background in model theory is very limited. Basically nothing past the definition of minimal structures and minimal subsets.  I am interested in some strategies that one might use to show that a structure, or a subset of the domain is not minimal.

By minimal I understand: 
An infinite structure, $A$ is minimal if any subset $Y$ of the domain of $A$, which is definable (with parameters) is either finite or cofinite. 
A subset $Y \subset A$ is minimal if, for any definable-with-parameters subset $Z$, then $Y \cap Z$ or $Y \setminus Z$ is finite.

Thank you!

Comment: In all the cases I know, you really have to do something much harder (namely, understand the definable sets in some way, e.g. by quantifier elimination) then basically notice it is true.  So for example if you talk about algebraically closed fields, you have quantifier elimination, and if you think about the open formulas in the field language, you clearly end up with the structure being minimal.  I'm not aware of any "more general" techniques, though.

Comment: @Richard Rast, The question is exactly the opposite: how to show that a structure is **not** minimal. I say find a definable set that is infinite and coinfinite. If you can't find such a set straight away there is a good chance that the structure is minimal.

Comment: Agh, I can't read.  But yes, definitely.  Proving something is not minimal is much easier, as most (?) of what you would guess almost at random is infinite and coinfinite, if there is one.